# copy and connect a part of an object

Tags: modeling, topology, freestyle

I have a stick with a protrusion on it:

[image]

and I want to copy the protrusion. I tryed to duplicate it and move along the stick, but in this case I get some problems: when I render it with freestyle I may get some unneeded lines and not get some lines i want to get:

[image]
[image]

and if I move the duplicate from the stick, it just disconnects without modification of the stick.

So, how can I connect the second protrusion to the stick or what is the correct way of coping such protrusions?

Answer (score 3):

### Work on model's topology

Freestyle takes also in account the topological features of each edge to determine whether or not it belongs to one of the Line set category (and so if it should be drawn).

You must ensure to provide to the software a model that could be interpreded the way you want.

---

Starting from a similar situation:

[image]

There are several different ways you can follow to model a similar object. In this case, for example, I choose to make room for the duplicating geometry by deleting the faces, duplicating the geometry and snapping it to the holeìs border.

[image] [image]

Now the geometry is in-place, but is not connected. Remove doubles operator is capable of joining the vertices (so relateded edges too) withing a given threshold.

[image]

Results:

[image] [image]

---

Another possible solution for this *specific* situation could be to leave intact the stick and just overlay a disconnected copy of the geometry.

You must **avoid overlapping faces** (overlapping edges shouldn't represent a big issue in this case) so you should duplicate only the selection shown in the images beleow:

[image] [image]

---

*Note: all "default" Frestyle line set style settings had been used in this demonstration apart from the Crease angle that hase been increased to 150°.*

Comment: Thank you for you answer, but how can I make room if the stick is not separated?

Comment: CTRL + R in **edit mode** will allow you to cut edges around a model. But all polygons and adjacent ones must have 4 vertices. (Nothing more nothing less only 4 vertices. You will need to get on youtube and look at some modeling tutorial. You would have learnt faster in regards to basic operations you can do in blender.